# Accessing stdin with 2 programs at the same time in Linux/Unix

Tags: c++, c, linux, stdin

I have read that stdin is a file in Linux/Unix. So, can 2 programs access the same stdin at the same time?? If yes, then how can this be done with C/C++??

Comment: Please, read [ask], read [ask] again to be sure, and read [ask] to be really really sure.

Comment: Don't ask theoretical questions.

Comment: Why?? Aren't theoretical questions supported by Stack Overflow??

Comment: You just do it; there's nothing special needed in C++ or any other language. But it's not a useful thing to do.

Comment: Yes. But exactly how do I access the same stdin with 2 separate programs. I mean like a user enters something in one stdin then how can it be accessed by 2 separate programs at the same time??

Comment: Do you mean if I type in "HELLO", both of those should go to 2 different programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's not a feature of specific programming languages, it's a feature of the operating system you're running on.

Look at this shell script example:

```
printf 'a\nb\n' | { { read x && echo $x; } <&0 & { read y && echo $y; }; }
```

Here, `{ read x && echo $x; }` will (likely) be executed as a separate process, and the same applies to `{ read y && echo $y; }`. Both processes read from the same `stdin`, which is the `a\nb\n` output from `printf`, so you should expect one of the processes to read `a`, and another to read `b`.

Worth pointing out is that this *doesn't* let both programs read both lines of input. Whichever program is first to read will see that bit of input. If you do need the same lines of input to go to two separate programs, you will need a program which copies the input to two different files or file descriptors. An example of a Unix utility which does this is `tee`. You can check to see how that's implemented for more details, if needed.

Comment: Thanks!Just what I was looking for.